# Website working on IE but not on Firefox

Tags: google-app-engine, firefox, internet-explorer-9

First timer.
I am working on a web application with Google-app-engine.
The code is mainly servlets and jsp.
When I run the local server and try to browse the site with IE9 it looks great.
But, when trying to do so with firefox10,11 or with GC, all I get are blank pages.
I deployed one page to the server and the problem reaccures.

If needed, I will add source-code or link to the page, but currently I've got nothing. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: We can't help without seeing the website or at least some of the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. Still learning my ways around here, after being a loyal reader for a few years. 
Anyway, I found it. It took me about 2 months, but I did. It is as simple as that: 
Seems like while IE is a bit more flexible, FF and GC can't parse a path with '/'s instead of '\'s. 
I got it when I installed Firebug for firefox and it ran over the code and implied that the URL for the images is invalid. A short look for that error message got me to that conclusion.

Thanks a lot!